# how to end up my outgoing call.

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

with `statrtActivity(callIntent)`, call goes and then i have to wait for few seconds and end automatically. to end up my call i have taken mycalss extends Broadcastreceiver then in that `onreceive()` i implemented.in that method i got only to set old number and newnumber and toast is printing.
What i want exactly is to end call what i need to write. and how to call onreceive method from my class? plase help me. i didnt get anywhere.

```
 @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {                                 
                    final String oldNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);         
                    this.setResultData(newPhNnumber);                                                   
                    final String newNumber = this.getResultData();
                    if((newNumber!=null)&&(newNumber!=oldNumber))
                    {
                    String msg = "Intercepted outgoing call. Old number " + oldNumber + ", new number " + newNumber;
                    Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    this.abortBroadcast();----> what it does?
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
try {
    Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
    Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
    m.setAccessible(true);
    ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);

    telephonyService.endCall();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but that doesn't seem to end the call. I used `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` to check for state and then to end it. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you simply abort outgoing call through following code

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (intent.getAction()
            .equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {

        phoneNo = intent
                .getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

        if (phoneNo.isBlocked(blockNo)) {
            setResultData(null);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add this "PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" permission if you did not add it?

Comment: Yeah i figure out.. I used phone state change broadcast instead of outgoing.. Thanks btw..