# How to end incoming/outgoing calls programatically in android?

Tags: android

I'm wondering how to end incoming/outgoing call programatically in android.
I tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408476/how-to-end-up-my-outgoing-call) but I got no luck in getting it work.

I am using following code to disconnect call using the BroadCast...

```
try{
       TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
       Class c = Class.forName(manager.getClass().getName());
       Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
       m.setAccessible(true);
       ITelephony telephony = (ITelephony)m.invoke(manager);
       telephony.endCall();
  } catch(Exception e){
       Log.d("",e.getMessage());
  }
```

but I got error:

```
NO such method name 'getITelephony' in ICS call is not disconnecting
```

Comment: You might want to be more specific about the "no luck" part. What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: every time I tried to make it work, I got error: No such method 'getITelephony'

Comment: There are many questions about this specific error. You should include at the very least the actual code you're using, the full error, a stack trace, your Android OS and SDK version, and show what you've already tried in order to solve the problem.

Comment: but all posts use the same solution (using getITelephony) method which is not available in android 2.3+

Comment: you may want to read this: http://hive-mind.org/android-call-blocking

Comment: So, is that your answer? Why are you suggesting yourself to read the link?

Comment: @slhck: I'm suggesting it for you :)

Comment: I'm asking if any one knows any other solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this way is not available any more in android 2.3+,
[this](http://hive-mind.org/android-call-blocking) article is discussing this issue